# Count of Neighborhoods Grouped by status

Tags: sql

I have a table that have Neighborhoods and Status columns

I want to get following 3 columns:
Neighborhood name,
Count StatusOpen,
Count StatusClosed

So far I have following and it's not working

```
select _c20 AS Neighborhood, 
  COUNT(select _c20 from events311_default_tbl WHERE _c5 = "Open" GROUP BY Neighborhood),
  COUNT(select _c20 from events311_default_tbl WHERE _c5 = "Closed" GROUP BY Neighborhood)
from events311_default_tbl
GROUP BY Neighborhood
```

Comment: Ta your question with the database you are using.

Comment: *How* is it not working??

Comment: It's on databricks, using magic %sql command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT _c20 as Neighborhood, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN _c5 = 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_open,
       SUM(CASE WHEN _c5 = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_closed
FROM events311_default_tbl
GROUP BY Neighborhood;
```